# Loop extract zip files and handle nested zips

Tags: command-line, batch, zip, 7-zip, extract

I have a command that will extract all zip files within a directory. The issue is you may have nested zip containers (zip inside a zip). What I would like it to do is go through one run, and then do a second loop. If it finds more zips, extract and loop again. Once the loop doesn't find anymore that haven't been extracted, it stops. Keep in mind, my zip extraction command is not deleting the original zip file on purposes (which I understand would probably make it easier if I were). Want this done via batch file please (no other languages like powershell, etc.).

```
for /F "DELIMS=" %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar *.7z') DO ( "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -aos -o"%%~dpnI%%~xI(ext)" "%%I"
```

I was able to hack it and do a manual loop numerous times to try to catch all the nested zips, but figured there might be a more reliable way.

```
SET /a VAR=0 
:HOME 
SET /a VAR=VAR+1
IF %VAR%==50 goto :End 
 
for /F "DELIMS=" %%I IN ('dir /b /s *.zip *.rar *.7z') DO ( "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe" x -aos -o"%%~dpnI%%~xI(ext)" "%%I" >>log.txt )
 
goto :HOME 
 
:END
pause
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `for /R` instead `for /F`:

```batch-file
@echo off && setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem :: check 7-zip\7z.exe in %path% variable :: 
2>nul 7z.exe >nul && set "_7z=7z.exe" && goto=%:^)

rem :: check 7-zip\7z.exe x86, 64 and W6432 variable :: 
for %%i in (ProgramFiles,ProgramFiles(x86^),ProgramW6432
)do if /i defined %%~i for /f tokens^=* %%z in ('2^>nul ^^^
where /r "!%%~i!\7-zip" 7z.exe')do set "_7z=%%~z" && goto=%:^)

rem :: one simple error message if 7-zip was not found
echo\7z.exe was not found in %% path %% variable and nor in...
echo\%%ProgramFiles%% ^| %%ProgramFiles(x86)%% ^| %%ProgramW6432%%

<con: rem./ && %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe  -1 & endlocal & goto=%:eof

%:^)
echo\Expanding: *.rar,*.zip,*.7z && for /r %%I in (*.rar,*.zip,*.7z
)do <con: "!_7z!" x -aos -o"%%~dpnI%%~xI(ext)" "%%~I" >>"%~dp0log.txt" 
<con: rem.// && %__APPDIR__%timeout.exe /t -1 & endlocal && goto=%:eof
```